# Erro ao forçar download arquivo XML C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, download

Tenho uma listagem de notas fiscais onde posso fazer o download do XML, porém há um servidor de uma empresa que abaixo do arquivo XML vem junto o HTML da página. O código para download do XML funciona normalmente em todos os servidores onde a aplicação está instalada exceto nesse cliente.
O método para download do arquivo é o seguinte:

```
 public void StreamFileToBrowser(string sFileName, byte[] fileBytes, string extensao)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Buffer = false;
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";//string.Format("application/{0}", extensao);
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileName);
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);           
    }
```

Alguma solução alternativa para forçar o download do arquivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema adicionando o seguinte código no final:

```
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.Close();
context.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu usaria apenas:

```
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=o_meu_ficheiro.xml");
context.Response.End();
```

é código que uso e sempre usei quando quero forcar o download de um ficheiro `XML` e funciona perfeitamente...

Comment: Vou tentar publicar um versão no servidor do cliente utilizando o código que me mostrou, mas ele está chamando todas essas funções justamente por nossas tentativas de resolver o problema. Talvez estivesse como o teu no início. Peguei esse código depois de outros tentarem resolver isso.

Comment: Não funcionou desse jeito. Alguma outra ideia?